# Undeclared Identifier using listboxes

Tags: delphi, listbox

I have created a listbox and used it to add and remove/load and save items to a file which is all well and good. However when I try to use the listbox on another unit, I get an error: *undeclared identifier*.

The first Unit below `MainUnit` is where I am trying to use the listbox and getting the error undeclared identifier. Below the `MainUnit`  is the `ManageUsersUnit` this is the unit in which the listbox is used and created. All the code works with the listbox on the `ManageusersUnit` but not on any other unit.

```
unit MainUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Menus, ExtCtrls;

implementation

uses AddTenantUnit, HomeUnit, MainMenuUnit;

{$R *.dfm}

{ the error im getting is in this procedure}

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);.
begin                                    
  if fileExists('Newuser.dat')
  then
    begin
      UserListBox.Items.LoadFromFile('Newuser.dat');
    end
  {endif};
end;
```

---

```
unit ManageUsersUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, MainUnit, StdCtrls, Menus, ComCtrls;

type
  TManageUsersForm = class(TForm)
    AddUserButton: TButton;
    RemoveUserButton: TButton;
    ChangeUsernameButton: TButton;
    ChangePasswordButton: TButton;
    HomeButton: TButton;
    UserListBox: TListBox;
    UsernameEdit: TEdit;
    SaveButton: TButton;
    PasswordEdit: TEdit;
    SubText1Label: TLabel;
    SubText2Label: TLabel;
    PassListBox: TListBox;
    Button1: TButton;

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  ManageUsersForm: TManageUsersForm;

implementation

uses PassWord, AddUserUnit, HomeUnit;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TManageUsersForm.HomeButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HomeForm.show;
  ManageUsersForm.Close;
end;

//Add UserName
procedure TManageUsersForm.AddUserButtonClick(Sender: TObject);

var
  i : integer;
  Found : Boolean;
  AddUser : string;

begin
  {ManageUsersForm.close;
  AddUserForm.ShowModal; }

  Found := false;
  AddUser := UsernameEdit.Text;

  i := 0;
  while i < userlistbox.Items.Count do
    begin
      if (UpperCase(AddUser) = Uppercase(userlistbox.Items[i]))
      then
        Found := True;
      inc(i);
    end;
  {endhwile};

  if Found = False then
    begin
      userlistbox.Items.Add(AddUser);
      UsernameEdit.Text := '';
      showMessage(AddUser + ' added');
    end
  else
    showMessage(AddUser + ' is already present.');
  {endif};
end;

procedure TManageUsersForm.RemoveUserButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  deleted : string;
begin
  with UserListBox do
    begin
      if ItemIndex = -1
      then
        showMessage('You must select a User first.')
      else
        begin
          Deleted := Items.Strings[ItemIndex];
          Items.Delete(ItemIndex);
          showMessage(Deleted + ' deleted');
        end;
      {endif};
    end;
end;

procedure TManageUsersForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
  Found : Boolean;
  check : string;
begin
  check := PasswordEdit.Text;
  Found := false;

  i := 0;
  while i < userlistbox.Items.Count do
    begin
      if (UpperCase(check) = Uppercase(userlistbox.Items[i]))
      then
        Found := True;
      inc(i);
    end;
  {endhwile};

  if Found = False
  then
    begin
      showMessage(check + ' Incorrect Username');
    end
  else
    showMessage(' well done in file :).');
  {endif};
end;

procedure TManageUsersForm.SaveButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  assignfile (userFile,'Newuser.dat');
  UserListbox.Items.SaveToFile('Newuser.dat');
  showMessage('Saved to file');
end;

procedure TManageUsersForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if fileExists('Newuser.dat')
  then
    begin
      UserListBox.Items.LoadFromFile('Newuser.dat');
    end
  {endif};
end;

procedure TManageUsersForm.TestBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    AddUserForm.ShowModal;
end;

end.
```

Comment: It looks like you know *using* units. Why don't you use 'ManageUsersUnit' too? `ManageUsersUnit.ManageUsersForm.UserListBox.Items.LoadFromFile('..`

Comment: The list box is inside a class. Should you really be poking at it from a different class in a different unit? Unfortunately for you, Delphi leads you to use these global variables and make UI objects visible everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `MainUnit` needs to use the `ManageUsersUnit` unit.  If the only references to the form in that other unit are in the `implementation` section then add it to the `uses` clause there.  As a general rule you should only add to the interface uses clause if absolutely necessary.

```
unit MainUnit;

///  ...

implementation

  uses AddTenantUnit, HomeUnit, MainMenuUnit, ManageUsersUnit;
```

Your code then references the `UserListBox` directly, but this reference is a member variable of the `TManageUsersForm` class, so you must first identify an instance of that class before you access the members of that instance.

In this case you appear to have a public instance already available which you presumably intend to use:  `ManageUsersForm`

So your code to load the file data into the list should be:

```
ManageUsersForm.UserListBox.Items.LoadFromFile('Newuser.dat');
```

This will fix your immediate issue.  However, there is a lot wrong with this approach.

1. **MainUnit** assumes that **ManageUsersForm** is a valid, existing form instance.  If the form is set to **AutoCreate** in the project then this may be valid but is dangerous since it makes your code
   vulnerable to a change in the way that your forms are created.
2. **MainUnit** is inappropriately responsible for some of the behaviour of the **ManageUsers** form.  If the ManageUsers form truly manages users then this should include persistence of users to/from files itself.
3. **MainUnit** is highly dependent upon the internal details of the **ManageUsers** form.  We say it is "tightly coupled".  If the ManageUsers form is modified to use, for example, a grid to a  listview to present users, the MainUnit code will break since it relies on the intimate knowledge that the users list is specifically a listbox.

As a result of the way that the VCL works, the user interface controls on a form in Delphi are publicly accessible, but you should regard these as **private** (or, at most, **protected**).  Your **ManageUsers** form should provide a public interface to the functionality that it provides to the "outside world" which deals in terms of user *data*.

There should be no references to the user interface elements of a form - including any event handlers - outside of the form itself (or descendant form classes if you are using an OO hierarchy of form classes).